# Middleware not executing on Nextjs 13.4 app routing

Tags: typescript, next.js, middleware, next.js13

I have a problem.
My middleware doesn't get executed...
This is my code:

```
export const config = {
  matcher: '/api/:function*',
};
```

This is the config I gave, it should only execute when the API gets a request.
I have the middleware.ts file inside my app/ folder.
Does someone know why this isn't working. I have the app routing version without the src/ folder selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place `middleware.ts` in the `src/` directory. It should be on the same level as `app` directory.

Comment: I love you <3 Nextjs made a very bad documentation. I though it would work by just putting it into the app folder.